# Automatic copy of a created dll of Qt5.2-msvc library while building

Tags: dll, qmake

I am using Qt5.2-msvc. I wrote a library project. I want to make a copy of the library(just the dll file) while building it to the another directory. 
I don't want to use DESTDIR since I just want to copy one single dll.
I have tried QMAKE_PRE_LINK and QMAKE_POST_LINK, but none of them works and gives me error.
Any guidance will be appreciated :)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your library project only builds one target (the DLL), then DESTDIR is probably what you want to use.  It only copies the TARGET, not other files.

Comment: What is your code and what is the error?